# Powershell - Creating Real64 WMI property failure

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to get Outlook OST files information and storing it in WMI. The size (in GB) has decimal values and then I need storing Real64 value. I am able storing it in string but I get a failure in Real64

```
If ($classOST -ine $null) {Remove-WmiObject -Class $Str_ClassNameOST}

[String]$Str_ClassNameOST="Outlook_OST"    #Nom de la classe 
$WMI_ClassOST = ""
$WMI_ClassOST = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass("Root\cimv2", 
$null, $null)
$WMI_ClassOST.name = $Str_ClassNameOST
$classOST = Get-WmiObject -Class $Str_ClassNameOST -List -Namespace 
'root\cimv2';

#OST
$colItemsOST = $null
$colItemsOST = (Get-ChildItem 
"$env:systemdrive\Users\racfr13\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" -Include 
*.OST -recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
If ($colItemsOST -ine $null) {

    Foreach ($OST in $colItemsOST) {

    $arglistOST = @{        
         Name    = $($_.Name) #Profile name             
         OST  = $($OST.name).ToString()  #Name of the OST            
         #Size = [math]::Round($OST.length / 1GB,3).ToString()     #Size of the OST
         Size = [math]::Round($OST.length / 1GB,3)     #Size of the OST
         LastWrite=$($ost.LastWriteTime).tostring('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm')       #When that profil was evaluate?
    }

    $WMI_ClassOST.Properties.Add("Name", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
    $WMI_ClassOST.Properties["Name"].Qualifiers.Add("key", $true)
    
    $WMI_ClassOST.Properties.Add("OST", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
    $WMI_ClassOST.Properties["OST"].Qualifiers.Add("key", $true)

    #$WMI_ClassOST.Properties.Add("Size", [System.Management.CimType]:: String, $false)
    $WMI_ClassOST.Properties.Add("Size", [System.Management.CimType]:: Real64, $false)
    $WMI_ClassOST.Properties["Size"].Qualifiers.Add("key", $true)

    $WMI_ClassOST.Properties.Add("LastWrite", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
    $WMI_ClassOST.Properties["LastWrite"].Qualifiers.Add("key", $true)

    $WMI_ClassOST.Put()
    
    Set-WmiInstance -Class $Str_ClassNameOST -Puttype CreateOnly -Argument $arglistOST
     
    }  
}
```

Then I get the error:

```
Exception lors de l'appel de « Add » avec « 2 » argument(s) : « La propriété 
ne peut pas être une clé  »
Au caractère C:\Sovgarde\Sans titre2.ps1:34 : 10
+          $WMI_ClassOST.Properties["Size"].Qualifiers.Add("key", $true ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ManagementException

Exception on call Add with 2 argument, the property cannot be a key
```

Any idea?

Comment: Reals and floats cannot be used as keys, but I doubt you'd want that anyway! Just remove that line completely, along with the one that adds the key qualifier to LastWrite

Comment: Mathias beat me to it but he's absolutely correct.  Documentation for key qualifier is 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/key-qualifier
and states
"You can use any property type except for the following:

Arrays,
Real and floating-point numbers,
Embedded objects,
Characters lower than ASCII 32 (that is, white space characters),
Character strings of type char16 or character strings that are defined as keys must contain values greater than U+0020. This is because WMI uses key values in object paths, and you cannot use nonprinting characters in an object path."

Comment: Sound great! I will do my test by commenting the line.